# FunctionIndexingException when missing ServiceBusConnectionString

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I create the following program:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;

namespace StayUpdated.Cpe.PypyFilter
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var jobHost = new JobHost();
            jobHost.RunAndBlock();
        }

        public static void ProcessQueue([ServiceBusTrigger("start")] String input)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In the app.config I add the following connection strings:

```
<add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=cpepypywebjobstorage;AccountKey=2iCufOrnXeY/B/VJptegGXaAbEmoj1SOgiiAbunk1kDAPqhkgvcOj3NEVGqtm0363GHu/h6Fy8JfoWEpKCP2Rw==" />
<add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=cpepypywebjobstorage;AccountKey=2iCufOrnXeY/B/VJptegGXaAbEmoj1SOgiiAbunk1kDAPqhkgvcOj3NEVGqtm0363GHu/h6Fy8JfoWEpKCP2Rw==" />
```

I get a `FunctionIndexingException` exception with message, `Error indexing method 'ProcessQueue'`.

Comment: I have struggled to find a solution to this and most suggestions were rather vague. My app config did not contain <appSettings> hence the error, however the description of the error/issue is vague too. Ensure that when creating an instance of either SubscriptionClient or TopicClient you do not pass null values (i.e. topicName, subscriptionsName, and so on) var client = SubscriptionHelper.GetSubscriptionClient(topicConnectionString, topicName, subscriberName);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is caused by the lack of an `AzureWebJobsServiceBus` connection string.  You must either add that connection string or manually connect a `ServiceBusConnectionString` via a `JobHostConfiguration`.

You can look at the inner exception on that exception and see that it is a `ConfigurationErrorsException` with a message:

> Configuration is missing required information. Make sure the property 'Endpoint' is defined as part of 'Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString' key within 'appSettings' section, or Windows Azure configuration settings.

Unfortunately, following the instructions provided in the exception message will not work.

I believe the cause is because without the service bus connection string, the JobHost doesn't load whatever it needs to load in order to successfully parse the `ServiceBusTrigger` attribute.

It would be much better if the error you received was along the lines of,

> Attempted to setup a ServiceBusTrigger without a ServiceBusConnectionString.

Even better would be to just log a warning that there are triggers that will never be hit and continue. One might want to have triggers setup but not always have a service bus connection string.

Comment: Yeah, the error message is highly misleading. Following the exact instructions results in the same error. And oddly enough, in a day-and-a-half or searching, this is the first reference I've found to the name 'AzureWebJobsServiceBus'.  Many thanks to you, and -1 to the Azure team for poor documentation!

Comment: where and in which format you put '`AzureWebJobsServiceBus`' ??

Comment: @ashish Add it to your app.config or web.config as a connection string.  See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: We will update this doc to explicitly mention the connectionstring http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-service-bus/ You can also look for more samples https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/ServiceBus